# Using Facebook SDK 4.9.1 safari freezes after successful login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, safari

I am using facebook SDK 4.9.1 to login to facebook, after successful login safari freezes and this message appear

Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

this is my custom login button action

```
@IBAction func loginFacebookAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString   
                print(accessToken)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

the access token is printed successfuly then safari freezes

## Edit

if I used FBSDKLoginButton not custom one it works, I don't know where is the problem

Comment: It looks you are using good way to login using Facebook SDK. try to read some official Facebook developer tutorial. i am sure you will get it.